# How does MonadTrans first law type check?

Tags: haskell

There is something I do not understand in the `MonadTrans` class laws.

`lift . return` is of type `a -> t m a`

`return` is of type `a -> m a`

How does  `lift . return = return` typecheck?

Comment: Laws for polymorphic functions (like `return`) often use the function at different types. E.g. the monad law `join . join = join . fmap join` can be quite confusing, since those `join`s are not the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some monad transformer `t` over some monad `m`, both `m` and `t m` are monads. Therefore, `return` may be instantiated to type `a -> m a` or `a -> t m a`.

In this scenario, `lift` has type `m a -> t m a`. Therefore, if we pick the type `a -> m a` for `return`, then `lift . return` has type `a -> t m a`. This is the other possible type for `return`, so the equivalence typechecks.

Here is the entire equivalence annotated with types:

```
(lift :: m a -> t m a) . (return :: a -> m a) = (return :: a -> t m a)
```

Comment: So the return in the left side is the implementation of return in a generic monad. And the return of the right side is the implementation of return in a monad transformer which is a monad as well. Am I saying it right?

Comment: @ΑχιλλέαςΜπαλακτσής Yes, that sounds correct. (More precisely, I'd say that the second one is the implementation of return in the transformed monad.)

Answer (score 2):

First: it should be understood that `return` of `m` and the `return` of `t m` are two different functions, which belong to two different instances.

The convention for the function composition `f . g` is the same as in the usual mathematical notation, that is, it must hold `g : x -> y` and `f: y -> z` for some types `x, y, z`.

The documentation states quite clearly that the type of `lift` is:

```
lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

that is, as soon as a `Monad` can be found for `m`, `lift` is essentially of type `m a -> t m a`.

We know that `return` which belongs to `m` has type `a -> m a`.

Thus, the two functions `return` and `lift` with types `a -> m a` and `m a -> t m a` are composable, their composition is the `return` of `t m`.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the types of `lift` and `return` first:

```
return ::  Monad m                =>   a ->   m a
lift   :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
```

Both do something similar: `return` lifts a value of any type into a monadic type wrapping the first type. `lift` lifts a value already wrapped in a monad into *another* monad created by the monad transformer. Because both the original monad `m` and the transformed monad `t m` have their own `return` function, you have two ways of putting a value of type `a` into a monad `t m a`:

1. Use the transformed monad's `return :: a -> t m a`
2. Use the original `return :: a -> m a`, then `lift :: m a -> t m a`.

The commutative diagram looks like

```
               return
           a  ------->  m a
           \            |
            \           | lift 
    return   \          |
              \         v
               +------ t m a
```

The first monad transformer law just states that it shouldn't matter which path you take to get from `a` to `t m a`.